# How to deploy AWS Lambda function with SAM, with choices feature?

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, aws-lambda, continuous-integration, devops

**Objective**: Deploy AWS Lambda function's with SAM in addition to the choices feature.

Context:
I have few lambda functions,
Like:

- get_recent_customer_visit()
- get_coupon_code()
- move_customer_to_premium()
- get_hot_products()
- get_customer_detail()

**Current Flow**:

- if i did changes in only `get_coupon_code()` function & then deploy.
- it forcefully deploy all lambda function (listed above) also

**Expected Flow**:

- if i did changes in only `get_coupon_code()` function & then deploy.
- So during deployment only `get_coupon_code()` function should deploy rather than deploy all lambda function
- So I plan to during deployment i pass the choices of a lambda function. Which I want to deploy

---

- I tried to fit the Expected Flow in CICD, But not get any solution :(
- If anyone knows the solution then please comment

Comment: Have you tried using sam deploy ?https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/tutorial-lambda-sam-deploy-update.html

Comment: Yes, @Shree. I not facing any issue during deployment (Current Flow). I wish / Mine requirement is that to deploy selected lambda function instead to all during CICD (Expected Flow), During deployment choose lambda function this kind of feature I not seen in AWS documentation.

Comment: With sam deploy, is the changeset listing all lambda functions even the ones that are not modified?